# How to use XDocument to Read Multiple Embeded Elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq, ienumerable, linq-to-xml

Here is a portion of the XML file I'm reading:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<movie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ThumbGen="1">
  <hasrighttoleftdirection>false</hasrighttoleftdirection>
  <title>A Nightmare on Elm Street</title>
  <originaltitle>A Nightmare on Elm Street</originaltitle>
  <year>1984</year>
  <plot>Years after being burned alive by a mob of angry parents, child murderer Freddy Krueger returns to haunt the dreams -- and reality -- of local teenagers. As the town's teens begin dropping like flies, Nancy and her boyfriend, Glen, devise a plan to lure the monster out of the realm of nightmares and into the real world.</plot>
  <tagline>A scream that wakes you up, might be your own...</tagline>
  <metascore>78</metascore>
  <trailer>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996</trailer>
  <rating>8.6</rating>
  <episodes />
  <episodesnames />
  <writers />
  <gueststars />
  <id>tt0087800</id>
  <releasedate>11.09.1984</releasedate>
  <actor>
    <name>Robert Englund</name>
    <name>Heather Langenkamp</name>
    <name>Johnny Depp</name>
    <name>Ronee Blakley</name>
    <name>John Saxon</name>
    <name>Amanda Wyss</name>
    <name>Jsu Garcia</name>
    <name>Charles Fleischer</name>
    <name>Joseph Whipp</name>
    <name>Lin Shaye</name>
    <name>Joe Unger</name>
    <name>Mimi Craven</name>
    <name>David Andrews</name>
  </actor>
  <genre>
    <name>Horror</name>
    <name>Comedy</name>
  </genre>
  <director>
    <name>Wes Craven</name>
  </director>
  <runtime>91</runtime>
  <certification>R</certification>
  <studio>
    <name>New Line Cinema</name>
  </studio>
  <country>
    <name>United States of America</name>
  </country>
  ...
  ...
  ...
</movie>
```

Thanks to Henk Holterman, I was able to clean up the code that is processing the XML, and I'm now using the following:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(n);  // takes care of all Open/Close issues
strTitle = doc.Root.Element("title") == null ? "" : doc.Root.Element("title").Value;
strYear = doc.Root.Element("year") == null ? "" : doc.Root.Element("year").Value;
strPlot = doc.Root.Element("plot") == null ? "" : doc.Root.Element("plot").Value;
strRating = doc.Root.Element("rating") == null ? "" : doc.Root.Element("rating").Value;
strMPAA = doc.Root.Element("mpaa") == null ? "" : doc.Root.Element("mpaa").Value;
strCertification = doc.Root.Element("certification") == null ? "" : doc.Root.Element("certification").Value;
```

Now for the last bit, how can I get the Genres from the genre Element using this method?  I can't search for the name Element since it is used in various other Elements.  I wasn't sure if I could work with:

```
doc.Root.Element("genre").ElementsAfterSelf("name");
```

Wasn't clear on what that returns (I don't QUITE understand how to use IEnumberables), or how it would handle multiple "names".  I figure it can be done with LINQ, but I am still trying to figure out how to use that.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: This does bot qualify as a new question, you just copied everything from the last one. Please edit so that it makes sense on its own.

Comment: If I were you I'd write a separate function something like `private string emptyOrValue(s) { return s == null ? string.Empty : s; }`.  Same code but would clean up the mess you have above considerably.  You can also do `(T)doc.Root.Element("year")` etc. to pull out T typed values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a list of genres:

```
// untested
List<string> genres = doc.Root
      .Element("genre")
      .Elements("name")
      .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```